# ¿Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in?

Tags: php, base-de-datos

Hola soy nuevo en esto de php quisiera que me ayudaran por favor estos son los errores que arroja

> Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\Register.php on line
>   4
>
> Notice: Undefined index: course in C:\xampp\htdocs\Register.php on
>   line 5
>
> Notice: Undefined index: surname in C:\xampp\htdocs\Register.php on
>   line 6
>
> Notice: Undefined index: user_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\Register.php on
>   line 7
>
> Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\Register.php on
>   line 8
>
> Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): Number of elements in type
>   definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Register.php on line 10 {"success":true}

y esto es mi código:

```
{<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "usuarios");

    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $course = $_POST["course"];
    $surname = $_POST["surname"];
    $user_name = $_POST["user_name"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO usuarios(name,course,surname,user_name,password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ssis", $name, $user_name, $course, $surname, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = true;  

    echo json_encode($response);
?>}
```

esto es del otro archivo

> Notice: Undefined index: user_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\Login.php on
>   line 4
>
> Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\Login.php on line
>   5
>
> Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be
>   mysqli_stmt, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Login.php on line 8
>
> Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt,
>   boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Login.php on line 9
>
> Warning: mysqli_stmt_store_result() expects parameter 1 to be
>   mysqli_stmt, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Login.php on line 11
>
> Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_result() expects parameter 1 to be
>   mysqli_stmt, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Login.php on line 12
>
> Warning: mysqli_stmt_fetch() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt,
>   boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Login.php on line 17
>   {"success":false}

código:

```
{<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "usuarios");

    $user_name = $_POST["user_name"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name = ? AND password = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $user_name, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $userID, $name, $course, $user_name,$surname, $password);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = false;  

    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
        $response["success"] = true;  
        $response["name"] = $name;
    $response["course"] = $course;
        $response["surname"] = $surname;
        $response["user_name"] = $user_name;
        $response["password"] = $password;
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
?>}
```

gracias

Answer (score 2):

Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow.

Tu error parece estar en esta línea:

<s>`mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ssis", $name, $user_name, $course, $surname, $password);`</s>

En los indicadores de tipo de dato (`"ssis"`) , estás pasando sólo cuatro, pero deben ser cinco.

Asumiendo que el único numérico que hay es `$course`, es evidente que tienes que poner la línea así:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ssiss", $name, $user_name, $course, $surname, $password);

//                                  12345
// 1. $name  
// 2. $user_name   
// 3. $course
// 4. $surname
// 5. $password
```

---

#### Nota de optimización del código

Tu código de inserción no verifica que realmente que ha habido una inserción. Pueden ocurrir errores aún con todo el código correcto, como por ejemplo, la inserción puede violar una restricción de la BD que impediría que se agregue un nuevo registro. Tu estarías devolviendo `TRUE` en ese caso de no inserción.

De modo que generalmente las inserciones **reales** se deben controlar con [**`mysqli_affected_rows`**](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.affected-rows.php).

Por ejemplo, aquí sólo devolvemos `TRUE` si hubo inserciones realmente:

```
//... todo lo anterior
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
//Contamos cuantas filas se insertaron y lo guardamos en una variable por si lo necesitamos
$count=mysqli_affected_rows($con);
//Usamos un ternario para devolver true si hubo inserciones solamente
$status=($count > 1) ? TRUE : FALSE;

//simplificamos
$response = array("success" => $status);

echo json_encode($response);
```

Se pueden hacer más cosas, como devolver el motivo del error por el que no hubo inserciones, devolver el número de filas, etc. Eso ya depende del contexto de tu programa.

Comment: y si $course no fuera numerico, de que forma quedaria?

Comment: En ese caso cambiarias la `i` por una `s`, y quedaría así: `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sssss", $name, $user_name, $course, $surname, $password);`

Comment: muchas gracias la verdad es que soy nuevo programando en android

Comment: @BryantAyala ¿te funcionó el código?

Comment: si me funciono gracias pero ahora tengo otro problema en la ultima fase de la etapa del desarrollo de mi app. gracias

Comment: @BriantAyala Me alegro de que la respuesta te haya ayudado a resolver el problema. Por favor, cuando sea posible l◔_◔: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) en el Centro de Ayuda. En cuanto al nuevo problema, lo puedes plantear en otra pregunta si no lo has hecho ya. Saludos.